# How to get the TCM custom protocol handler working in Internet Explorer 64-bit?

Tags: internet-explorer, tridion, protocol-handler

One of the features of Tridion I use a lot is its "protocol handler". For those not familiar with that feature: if you paste the TCM URI (e.g. `tcm:1-23-32`) into the address bar of Internet Explorer on a machine where Tridion Content Manager is installed, it will show you the XML of that item.

But I noticed that this feature doesn't work in the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer 9. Does anyone here know what I need to do to make it work in the 64-bit version too?

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 + HR1, but I don't think this problem/question is specific to that version of Tridion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that "protocol handler" is 32-bit COM object, so as workaround you can put COM component to COM+ application, but anyway the described feature is only side effect of main purpose of the protocol handler (handling TCM URIs in XSLT templates). And most probably this side effect feature won't be there anymore in upcoming version(s).